# How do I pretty print or visualise an object of class 'CoreNLP_pb2.ParseTree' in Python/Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanza's CoreNLP client in a Jupyter notebook to do constituency parsing on a string. The final output came in the form of an object of class 'CoreNLP_pb2.ParseTree'.

```
>>> print type(result)
<class 'CoreNLP_pb2.ParseTree'>
```

How should I print this in a visible way? When I directly call `print(result)`, there is no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conver `CoreNLP_pb2.ParseTree` into `nltk.tree.Tree` and the call `pretty_print()` to print the parse tree in a visible way.

```py
from nltk.tree import Tree
def convert_parse_tree_to_nltk_tree(parse_tree):
    return Tree(parse_tree.value, [get_nltk_tree(child) for child in parse_tree.child]) if parse_tree.child else parse_tree.value

convert_parse_tree_to_nltk_tree(constituency_parse).pretty_print()
```

The result is as follows:

```
                      ROOT                    
                       |                       
                       S                      
        _______________|____________________   
       |                    VP              | 
       |            ________|___            |  
       NP          |            NP          | 
   ____|_____      |    ________|_____      |  
 NNP        NNP   VBZ  DT       JJ    NN    .
  |          |     |   |        |     |     |  
Chris     Manning  is  a       nice person  .
```